# How can I use Python to perform an operation on a JSON value?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file I'm parsing. As part of the operations I'm performing on the file, I need to subtract the `yardLine` key from 100 in any element with value `"ORE"` in key `"homeAbbr"`. It doesn't matter if the code updates the original `yardLine` key's value or creates a new `yardLineReal` key with the modified value - I've tried both ways but it seems logical that the new key would be easier to create so as not to loop infinitely. Here's a sample of two elements of the JSON - every element has the same keys:

```
{
        "gameId": "400935253",
        "year": 2017,
        "week": 1,
        "homeId": "2483",
        "homeTeam": "Oregon",
        "homeAbbr": "ORE",
        "awayId": "253",
        "awayTeam": "Southern Utah",
        "awayAbbr": "SUU",
        "driveIndex": "2",
        "playIndex": "1",
        "offenseId": "2483",
        "offenseTeam": "Oregon",
        "offenseAbbr": "ORE",
        "defenseId": "253",
        "defenseTeam": "Southern Utah",
        "defenseAbbr": "SUU",
        "homeScore": 7,
        "awayScore": 7,
        "isScore": false,
        "quarter": 1,
        "clock": "11:39",
        "type": "Rush",
        "down": 1,
        "distance": 10,
        "yardLine": 26,
        "yardsGained": 14,
        "endYardLine": 40,
        "description": "Royce Freeman run for 14 yds to the Oregn 40 for a 1ST down"
    },
    {
        "gameId": "400935253",
        "year": 2017,
        "week": 1,
        "homeId": "2483",
        "homeTeam": "Oregon",
        "homeAbbr": "ORE",
        "awayId": "253",
        "awayTeam": "Southern Utah",
        "awayAbbr": "SUU",
        "driveIndex": "2",
        "playIndex": "2",
        "offenseId": "2483",
        "offenseTeam": "Oregon",
        "offenseAbbr": "ORE",
        "defenseId": "253",
        "defenseTeam": "Southern Utah",
        "defenseAbbr": "SUU",
        "homeScore": 7,
        "awayScore": 7,
        "isScore": false,
        "quarter": 1,
        "clock": "11:39",
        "type": "Rush",
        "down": 1,
        "distance": 10,
        "yardLine": 40,
        "yardsGained": 3,
        "endYardLine": 43,
        "description": "Royce Freeman run for 3 yds to the Oregn 43"
    }
```

And here's the non-functional code I came up with, trying to create a new key called `yardLineReal` with the edited value (my non-functional code to edit the value directly in `yardLine` only differs in the name of the key in line 8):

```
import json

with open ('data.json', 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for element in data:
    if 'ORE' in element["homeAbbr"]:
        data[yardLineReal] = 100 - data[yardLine]

with open('data.json', 'w') as data_file:
    data = json.dump(data, data_file)
```

I don't believe the code calls the value associated with `yardLine` as written. I suppose the question boils down to, is there a way to reference this value?

Thanks :)

Comment: `data[yardLineReal]` means `data[THE-VALUE-OF-THE-VARIABLE-yardLineReal]`. If `yardLineReal` is set to `foo`, that means `data["foo"]`. What you want is `data["yardLineReal"]`. Same for `data[yardLine]`

Comment: You are missing the quotes around the keys. It should be data["key"] (`data["yardLine"]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just update `element` itself. This will cause `data` to also be updated:

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for element in data:
    if 'ORE' in element['homeAbbr']:
        element['yardLineReal'] = 100 - element['yardLine']

with open('data.json', 'w') as data_file:
    data = json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! For anybody looking for a similar solution, `yardLine` can be edited directly as well as pushed to `yardLineReal`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can calls the value associated with "yardLine" as written

this code is work!

```
for k, element in enumerate(data):
    if 'ORE' in element['homeAbbr']:
        data[k]['yardLine'] = 100 - element['yardLine']
```

Result:

```
{'awayAbbr': 'SUU',
  'awayId': '253',
  'awayScore': 7,
  'awayTeam': 'Southern Utah',
  'clock': '11:39',
  'defenseAbbr': 'SUU',
  'defenseId': '253',
  'defenseTeam': 'Southern Utah',
  'description': 'Royce Freeman run for 3 yds to the Oregn 43',
  'distance': 10,
  'down': 1,
  'driveIndex': '2',
  'endYardLine': 43,
  'gameId': '400935253',
  'homeAbbr': 'ORE',
  'homeId': '2483',
  'homeScore': 7,
  'homeTeam': 'Oregon',
  'isScore': False,
  'offenseAbbr': 'ORE',
  'offenseId': '2483',
  'offenseTeam': 'Oregon',
  'playIndex': '2',
  'quarter': 1,
  'type': 'Rush',
  'week': 1,
  'yardLine': 60, # before 40
  'yardsGained': 3,
  'year': 2017}
```

Answer (score -2):

Once you load a JSON file into Python it becomes a dictionary. You can iterate through it like this:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    if value == something:
        new_value = do_something(value)
        data[key] = new_value
```

I'm not really sure what exactly you're trying to do, but this should help you get started.

Comment: There's no need of iterating through the whole dictionary. The OP wants to perform operations on a specific key which can be achieved in `O(1)`. Your solution is `O(n)`.

Comment: As I understood the problem, he wants to check for specific values, which means he'll have to iterate through the keys, doesn't it?